# Is Latin "porrige" connected to middle ages "porridge"?

Tags: etymology

Is Latin word "porrige", to stretch, connected in any way to "porridge", the cereal made by stretching oats/ grain by adding water?

Comment: When asking about etymology, you should always look up the origins of the word you’re asking about if you can find it. Good places to find etymologies are [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org). If you look up the word there and don’t find an answer, feel free to edit your question to add in what you did learn and what it is you’re still wondering about.

Comment: 'porrige' doesn't sound very Latiny. Where did you find that it is Latin?

Comment: @Mitch: See [William Whitaker's Words](http://archives.nd.edu/words.html).   
[**porrige**](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=porrige): V 3 1 PRES ACTIVE IMP 2 S  
porrigo, porrigere, porrexi, porrectus  V  
stretch out, extend

Comment: @Raven Oh OK...then making that explicit should be part of the OP. (also it's not the infinitive as the OP claims but the imperative?)

Comment: @Mitch : The OP _did_ call it a Latin word; where she saw it was unstated; perhaps a hardcopy book though, in which case a link would not have been possible. _We_ can easily look up words too. As to why that particular mood of the verb was chosen? I presume because that form, "porrige", most closely resembles the English word "porridge", and she wondered whether it was more than coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Janus suggests [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=porridge), which says porridge derives "from Latin *porrum* 'leek.'"

Comment: Hello, Raven. The **reason** Janus put this in a 'comment' rather than an 'answer' is because the question should be closed as lacking reasonable research (see the Help Center). OP could readily find the information given in Etymon for themself. Giving an 'answer' sends out a wrong message to visitors, conveying a veneer of respectability, when the question doesn't conform to the reasonable expectations laid out in the Help Center.. The correct procedure is to close-vote (and many believe that supplying an 'answer', or perhaps better a pointer or two, in a 'comment' is justifiable).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth : At the time, as a new user, I was not allowed to add a comment, just an answer.

Comment: We've all been there, Raven. Frustrating, but correct practice.